# Boot an old Win7 32bit parition from Win7 64bit in VMware workstation

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, virtual-machine, vmware, 32-bit

Could anyone help me achieve this, I have tried this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/155533/how-can-i-run-my-ubuntu-partition-in-windows-vmware) but had no joy. It just has a black screen with various text such as DCHP xyz ./ culminating in it saying operating system not found.

The partition is on a different physical disk.

Any suggestions?

Many thanks.

Comment: This means Windows is having problems adjusting to the new configuration.  They only way I know how to do a migration like this is to use paid software.

Comment: @Ramhound VMware Workstation is paid software? http://store.vmware.com/store/vmwde/en_GB/buy/productID.166452200