# Running Dual-Boot ubuntu within windows causes reboot

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, vmware, multi-boot

I am attempting to run Ubuntu within Windows. The Ubuntu is actually dual booted on my computer.

I am running VmWare workstation in Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.10. I am attempting to do this using this method:
[How can I run my ubuntu partition in Windows? vmware?](https://superuser.com/questions/155533/how-can-i-run-my-ubuntu-partition-in-windows-vmware)

However, when I do it simply shuts down the VM and restarts it. So I'm not sure what is causing this. Anyone else had this issue?

Comment: By "The Ubuntu is actually dual booted on my computer", do you mean that you have a separate partition completely - or that you did the WUBI installer (i.e. the Ubuntu installer from inside Windows)?

Comment: Separate partition completely