# Boot physical partition as a VM

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

I have a physical Ubuntu partition on my HDD that it would occasionally like to boot inside Windows as a VM for file transfer between Windows and Ubuntu and non-intensive tasks inside Ubuntu.

How can I achieve this with VMWare Workstation?

Or do I need to purchase different VM software to achieve this goal?

Comment: Download the vmware converter and convert the maschine to use it as a vm but you may run into conflicts running a duplicate as an vm while running the physical maschine as well. What do you want to achive by running your physical pc as a vm? Testing purpose? Maybe its easier to answer if you add more detail of your intention.

Comment: I've done this with Virtualbox (it's free), but it's quite tricky to set up bootloaders. Basically you need a separate boot partition for the VM. I think you can to this even with VMware Player, so Workstation should work too.

Comment: Ah this seems to hold the answer http://superuser.com/questions/155533/how-can-i-run-my-ubuntu-partition-in-windows-vmware